# How to get any three rows of particular date in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am stucking in one sql query.

My table format is the below:

```
Acct#    AdmitDate                 DOS                   ChargeAmount
12366   2011-12-07 00:00:00.000   2011-12-15 00:00:00.000   25.00
12366   2011-12-07 00:00:00.000   2011-12-16 00:00:00.000   30.00
12366   2011-12-07 00:00:00.000   2011-12-17 00:00:00.000   55.00
12366   2011-12-07 00:00:00.000   2011-12-18 00:00:00.000   48.00
12366   2011-12-07 00:00:00.000   2011-12-19 00:00:00.000   25.00
12366   2012-01-08 00:00:00.000   2012-01-08 00:00:00.000   58.00
12366   2012-01-08 00:00:00.000   2012-01-09 00:00:00.000   46.00
12366   2012-01-08 00:00:00.000   2012-01-10 00:00:00.000   90.00
12366   2012-01-08 00:00:00.000   2012-01-11 00:00:00.000   52.00
12366   2012-01-08 00:00:00.000   2012-01-12 00:00:00.000   95.00
12366   2012-01-08 00:00:00.000   2012-01-13 00:00:00.000   53.20
```

I want only top 3 **DOS** by one **Admit Date** and sum of their **ChargeAmount**. All the other DOS should be neglact. 
I have no idea how to do this.  I want the below desired output.

```
Acct#   AdmitDate                 ChargeAmount
12366   2011-12-07 00:00:00.000   128.00
12366   2012-01-08 00:00:00.000   200.00
```

only 2011-12-17 to 2011-12-19 for Admit Date 2011-12-07 need to be sum and do the same for other Admit date.
If you have any sql query please share with me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select 
Acct#,
AdmitDate,
sum(ChargeAmount) ChargeAmount
from
(Select 
Acct#,
AdmitDate,
row_number() over(partition by AdmitDate order by DOS desc) RowNo,
ChargeAmount
from TableName
where Acct# = @AcctNumber
) as t

where (RowNo = 1 or RowNo = 2 or RowNo = 3)

group by Acct#, AdmitDate
```

I have found the query. This query is working fine for me. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT TOP 3 Acct, AdmitDate, SUM(ChargeAmount)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Acct, AdmitDate
```

**Edit**

```
SELECT Acct, AdmitDate, SUM(ChargeAmount)
, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY AdmitDate ORDER BY AdmitDate DESC)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Acct, AdmitDate
```

Comment: Both misread this one mate. He wants only the three largest ChargeAmounts per Acct and admitdate. Looks like one of them rank over partition jobbies I've been meaning to learn

Comment: @DarrenDavies - Your query returns the sum of ChargeAmount of all rows of one AdmitDate but I want sum only top three rows of one Admit Date. I have already shown the example above. Please do the needful.

Comment: @DineshKumar Iknow you put please in there, but it comes like a across demand.